# Switching Spaces with 3-finger swipe, focus is still on the previous Space

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, spaces, multi-touch

I recently upgraded my 2018 MacBook Pro running Mojave to a 2023 MacBook Pro running Ventura. Since the upgrade, I've noticed some differences in behavior that weren't present before.

My primary browser is Google Chrome, and I typically have it running full-screen across two Spaces (essentially, this means I have two separate windows of Chrome tabs, each maximized on its own Space). I frequently use a three-finger swipe to navigate between these Spaces.

Here's the issue: After I swipe from one Space to another (transitioning from one Chrome window to the next), and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab, the new tab opens in the Chrome window located in the previous Space, not the current one. This seems to happen because the Chrome window in the new Space isn't automatically focused until I manually click on it.

Is this behavior expected in Ventura? If not, how can I ensure that pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> always opens a new tab in the Chrome window of the currently active Space?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an exact solution to this problem but this works.

Once you do the three-finger swipe, you can then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

This will bring your focus to the screen that is in front of you. If you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> after this, then your new tab will open in the window in front of you.

Another way which is helpful is that instead of using three-finger swipe to move to next space of Chrome, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> to move to next space. This will automatically bring your focus to the next space of Chrome and you can simply do <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open a new tab in there.

Let me know if you find a solution which can automatically shifts focus to the space after three-finger swipe.